# React Native Unmount component before navigation goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, use-effect, react-navigation-stack

I have a screen that has content that is updated by and api call. Whenever I leave the screen, I want to unmount the component so that the next time it is rendered again, because the api is called with different data. Right now, if I enter for the first time, everything works fine (activity indicator shows that it is loading and info is display), but if I go back and then enter again to view the info for another id, it shows the previously loaded information and only after a time it reloads (without the activity indicator displaying). I don't mind the delay, but at least I would like the activity indicator to be displayed while loading.

```
const AllReservationsScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        tableHead: ['Car Number', 'Reserved From', 'Expiration Time', 'Reserved By'],
        reservations: "",
        isLoading: true
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(async() => {
            ReservationService.getReservationsByParkingSpot(route.params.parkingSpotId, route.params.token).then(
                (response) => {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        return;
                    }

                    setData({
                        ... data,
                        isLoading: false,
                        reservations: convertReservationsToArray(response.data)
                    });
                }
            );
        }, 1000);
    }, [isFocused]);

    const convertReservationsToArray = (reservations) => {
        let reservationsArray = [];
        reservations.map(
            (reservation) =>
                reservationsArray.push(
                    [
                        reservation.registrationPlateNumber,
                        moment(reservation.startTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY HH:mm'),
                        moment(reservation.endTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY HH:mm'),
                        reservation.user
                    ]
                )
        );
        return reservationsArray;
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.modal}>
            <View style={styles.titleView}>
                <View style={styles.titleDetails}>
                    <Icon
                        name='ios-arrow-back'
                        size={30}
                        color='#8ea7f8'
                        onPress={() => {
                            setData({
                                ... data,
                                isLoading: true,
                                reservations: []
                            });
                            navigation.goBack()
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>All Reservations</Text>
            <View style={styles.modalForm}>
                {
                    data.isLoading ? (
                        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                            <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
                        </View>
                    ) : (
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'transparent'}} style={{borderRadius: 10}}>
                                <Row data={data.tableHead} style={styles.headStyle} textStyle={styles.headText}/>
                                <ScrollView>
                                    {
                                        //console.log(data.reservations)
                                        data.reservations.map(
                                            (reservation, i) => {
                                                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                                                    return <Row
                                                        key={i}
                                                        data={reservation}
                                                        style={styles.evenRow}
                                                        textStyle={styles.tableText}
                                                    />
                                                } else {
                                                    return <Row
                                                        key={i}
                                                        data={reservation}
                                                        style={styles.oddRow}
                                                        textStyle={styles.tableText}
                                                    />
                                                }
                                            }
                                        )
                                    }
                                </ScrollView>
                            </Table>
                        </View>
                    )
                }
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigation.pop()` instead of the `goBack()`, they are exactly the same the only difference is that `pop` removes the current component.

see: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#pop

And because you use `useEffect` you should in the beginning of that function set loading to true again! `useEffect` works like `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` so you want to be loading everytime you're calling the api. Or just use `componentDidMount`.